# How to perform query with multiple children?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make an activity that shows classes and lists them in a recyclerview. However, I am having a problem querying my data from firebase. I will explain more after i show my database structure. Here is my database structure:

```
"Classes": {
    "-Li9nBUgnFmCWqUmwV5W": {
        "class_info": {
            "date_clasname": "August 6, 2019",
            "room_number": "131",
            "subject": "Science",
            "teacher": "Ms.Henry",
            "id": "-Li9nBUgnFmCWqUmwV5W"
        }
    },
    "-Li9n_IYwbTNPdNAsTAu": {
        "class_info": {
            "date_clasname": "August 6, 2019",
            "room_number": "131",
            "subject": "Math",
            "teacher": "Ms.Henry",
            "id": "-Li9n_IYwbTNPdNAsTAu"
        }
    },
    "-Li9naUipsa865NBpZjW": {
        "class_info": {
            "date_clasname": "August 6, 2019",
            "room_number": "131",
            "subject": "Other",
            "teacher": "Ms.Henry",
            "id": "-Li9naUipsa865NBpZjW"
        }
    },
    "-Li9nbpwp2qchwmZRDP9": {
        "class_info": {
            "date_clasname": "August 6, 2019",
            "room_number": "131",
            "subject": "Technology",
            "teacher": "Ms.Henry",
            "id": "-Li9nbpwp2qchwmZRDP9"
        }
    },
    "-Li9ne0NDyjcB4SIWi1z": {
        "class_info": {
            "date_clasname": "August 6, 2019",
            "room_number": "131",
            "subject": "Social Studies",
            "teacher": "Ms.Henry",
            "id": "-Li9ne0NDyjcB4SIWi1z"
        }
    }
},
```

I am trying to query the classes by subject and only show the ones whose subject is "Science". I have tried a variety of things, but still can't figure out how to do it. Here is the code for my activity:

```
public class Science_classes extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private  DatabaseReference myRef, newmf;
   private List<Listdata> list;
   private RecyclerView recyclerview;
  String class_value = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_science_classes);
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rview);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("Classes");
    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


            String id = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            Query query = myRef.child(id).child("class_info").orderByChild("subject").equalTo("Science");
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Class_model new_class = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Class_model.class);
                        String nameofclass = new_class.getDate_clasname();
                        String teacherofclass = new_class.getTeacher();
                        String roomnumberofclass = new_class.getRoom_number();
                        String class_key = new_class.getUid();
                        Listdata listdata = new Listdata(nameofclass, teacherofclass, roomnumberofclass, class_key);
                        //String name = userdetails.getName();
                        //String email = userdetails.getEmail();
                        //String address = userdetails.getAddress();
                        listdata.setDate_class(nameofclass);
                        listdata.setTeacher(teacherofclass);
                        listdata.setRnumber(roomnumberofclass);
                        list.add(listdata);
                    }
                    RecyclerviewAdapter2 recycler = new RecyclerviewAdapter2(list);
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(Science_classes.this);
                    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
                    recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerview.setAdapter(recycler);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }



        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }
    @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


    }
```

I think my problem might be that i can't get the random generated id and set that as my child before my other child "class_info" in my onChildAdded.
Thank you!

Comment: What is the output? from what I see, all looks good.

Comment: @Ticherhaz it is blank when i run it... there is no error, but it says "Consider adding '".indexOn": "subject"' at Classes/Class_info to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance"

Comment: have you checked the security rules at Firebase?

Comment: i don't have that in my rules because i dont know how to add it. My current rules are:{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
   ".write":"auth != null"
  }
}

Comment: ^above @Ticherhaz

Comment: try change it to public first. according to this . https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart

Comment: I have a login page, so that wouldn't matter @Ticherhaz

Comment: have you take a look for FirebaseUi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building the query like this:

```
Query query = myRef.child(id).child("class_info").orderByChild("subject").equalTo("Science");
```

This says to find a child by `id` (which I think is not showing in your JSON) and then find a child `class_info`, then under that find the `subject` property of each child and filter on that. So the path is `$id/class_info/*/subject`, where `*` is the child nodes that you want to filter and return.

But what you actually have is `/Classes/*/class_info/subject`. So you have a node `Classes` of which you want to return the child nodes whose `class_info/subject` has the given value. In code this is:

```
DatabaseReference classesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Classes");

Query query = classesRef.orderByChild("class_info/subject").equalTo("Science");

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Class_model new_class = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Class_model.class);
            ...
```